# Questions about SwiftUI Layout

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to place a Button inside a TextField

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("ADD WORD")) {
        HStack {
            TextField("input word", text: $dictionaryVM.inputText)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    
            Button(action: {
                showDetailView = true
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName:"plus")
            })
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.trailing, -10)
            }
     }
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]
I draw a red border on the screenshot 1 image, when I click outside that red border, it'll trigger the button action
[image: Screenshot 2]
and When I click the button, like the screenshot 2 showed, the whole TextField turned gray, I don't know what I did is wrong, please help me out.

Comment: Change the list to a VStack. List kind of merges gestures

Comment: How the `showDetailView` value affects the view? Please include that code as well.